# SQL Error: ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am getting issue while inserting a new record to the table in Oracle database. The error description says-

> SQL Error: ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

How would I come to know that which column is having large value as I am having 60 columns in the table.

Comment: Can you please tell us version of your database? You tagged it as 10g,  however, it seems to be 9i because ora 01401 was replaced in 10g by ora 12899, which is mentioned in @Lalit s answer. In 10g the column name is included in err msg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SQL Error: ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

You are trying to insert value larger than the specified size for the column.

> How would I come to know that which column is having large value as I am having 60 columns in the table.

The error will certainly have the table and column name with the actual size being inserted and the maximum size allowed.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A VARCHAR2(2));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('123');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('123')
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "LALIT"."T"."A" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)


SQL>
```

In the above example, the error clearly states "column "**LALIT"."T"."A" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)**" where **LALIT** is the `SCHEMA`, **T** is the `TABLE` and **A** is the `COLUMN`. The size specified for column A while table creation was 2, however, the actual insert had 3.

**UPDATE** Regarding confusion between `ORA-01401` and `ORA-12899`.

From Oracle 10g and higher, the `ORA-01401` was modified to `ORA-12899` which is more explicit and has the details about the SCHEMA, TABLE and the COLUMN which caused the error.

**Additional information** Just in case if anyone is interested:

There is a counterpart of `ORA-01401`, i.e. `ORA-01438` which is applicable in case of NUMBER. This seems to be unchanged.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A number(2));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (123);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (123)
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL>
```

Comment: Please see my above comment to the question, ORA-12899 was introduced in 10g

Comment: Yes, I saw the `oracle10g` tag. OP should see the error message in the error stack.

Comment: ... unless he mixed up versions . Which probably did.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I checked MOS, thought to add an update. See my updated answer. It should remove any confusions.